# Run a specific command in all pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I was wondering if it is possible to run a specific command (Example: echo "foo") at a specific time in all existing pods (pods that are not in the default namespace are included). It would be like a cronJob, but the only difference is that I want to specify/deploy it in one place only. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Please find the steps I followed, hope it help you.

First, create a simple script to read pod's name, `exec` and execute the command.

```
import os, sys
import logging
from datetime import datetime

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)

dt = datetime.now()
ts = dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S-%f")

pods = os.popen("kubectl get po --all-namespaces").readlines()

for pod in pods:
    ns = pod.split()[0]
    po = pod.split()[1]

    try:
        h = os.popen("kubectl -n %s exec -i %s sh -- hostname" %(ns, po)).read()
        os.popen("kubectl -n %s exec -i %s sh -- touch /tmp/foo-%s.txt" %(ns, po, ts))
        logging.debug("Executed on %s" %h)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

Next, Dockerize the above script, build and push.

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV KUBECTL_VERSION=v1.18.0

WORKDIR /foo

ADD https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${KUBECTL_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl .

RUN chmod +x kubectl &&\
    mv kubectl /usr/local/bin

COPY foo.py .

CMD ["python", "foo.py"]
```

Later we'll use this image in CronJob. You can see I have installed kubectl in the Dockerfile to trigger the kubectl commands. But it is insufficient, we should add `clusterole` and `clusterrolebinding` to the service account which runs the CronJob.

I have created a ns `foo` and I bound foo's default service account to cluster role I created as shown below.

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: foo
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: foo
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: foo
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: foo
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Now service account default of foo has permissions to `get, list, exec` to all the pods in the cluster.

Finally create a cronjob to run the task.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  schedule: "15 9 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: foo
            image: harik8/sof:62177831
            imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Login to the pods and check, it should have created file with timestamp at `/tmp` directory of each pod.

```
$ kubectl exec -it app-59666bb5bc-v6p2h sh           
# ls -lah /tmp          
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun  4 09:15 foo-04-06-2020-09-15-06-792614.txt
```

logs

```
error: cannot exec into a container in a completed pod; current phase is Failed
error: cannot exec into a container in a completed pod; current phase is Succeeded
DEBUG:root:Executed on foo-1591262100-798ng

DEBUG:root:Executed on grafana-5f6f8cbf75-jtksp

DEBUG:root:Executed on istio-egressgateway-557dcf8d8-npfnd

DEBUG:root:Executed on istio-ingressgateway-6489d9556d-2dp7j

command terminated with exit code 126
DEBUG:root:Executed on OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"hostname\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

DEBUG:root:Executed on istiod-774777b79-mvmqm
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The reason I asked this question in StackOverflow, was because I wanted to see if there is a `kubernetes only` way to do this. But as it seems that doesn't exist. Your approach with a python script seems really easy to do, so I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but a bit complicated and you would need to write everything yourself, as there is no automatic tools to do that as far as I'm aware.

You could use Kubernetes API to collect all `pod` names, use those in a loop to push `kubectl exec pod_name command` to all those pods.

To list all `pods` in a cluster `GET /api/v1/pods`, this will also list the system ones.

This `script` could be run using Kubernetes [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) at your specified time.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
for ns in $(kubectl get ns -oname | awk -F "/" '{print $2}'); do for pod in $(kubectl get po -n $ns -oname | awk -F "/" '{print $2}'); do kubectl exec $pod -n $ns echo foo; done; done
```

It will return en error if `echo` (or the command) is not available in the container. Other then that, should work.